# Document ID service not working properly, assigning wrong number

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-id

After we installed a SharePoint Server 2010 CU, we noticed that the document ID service started showing strange behaviour.

It follows the same template as before: `[Prefix]-[List ID]-[Item ID]`, where we would expect a new list on a site to have an ID of 1.

Now it seems as though it assigns a random 8/9 digit number.

We use scripts and templates to create new sites and their new lists so we would a list with ID 1 to correspond to a certain type of list or library. The random numbers are an inconvenience and aren’t isolated to new sites.

Does anyone have any advice on how to flush this out?

I appreciate lists/libraries that have already been created cannot be reset but I would like to have new lists begin exhibiting normal behaviour again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a look online, there aren't that many resources around that describe this issue. However, i came across this article on Microsoft Technet

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2eee53a3-852c-4665-acfe-07da4c6d6bbe/where-does-the-middle-portion-of-the-document-id-come-from-now?forum=sharepointdevelopment

This describes that the change came from a CU update.  There had been a bug in the way the original small List ID number had been assigned previously.  This forced Microsoft to come up with a Hashing algorthim to generate the List ID portion of the DocId instead, hence the ballooning of the generated number.

The article explains that this number can be changed on the specific libraries with Powershell, however i would fully test this before deploying to see what affect it has on your setup. You may want to record List Id's that you have manually set to ensure you dont duplicate within the system.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks very much Chris, that makes sense, we came from SP2 to Sep2016 CU so thats why it happened recently, that article is for SP2013 but I assume it is the same for 2010